# SQL, selecting transactions per hour, per user

Tags: sql, date, group-by

Im struggling to work out how to display my data per USER, per HOUR

I need it to look like this.

For a 24 hour period, total transactions per hour, per user

```
      0600    0700    0800    0900 etc
Brian   4       3        4       2
Ange    0       2        1       1
Simon   0       0        1       1
```

The data looks like this.....

```
GENERATED_DATE          RAC_FULLNAME
2020-04-23 06:37:48.000 Brian                   
2020-04-23 06:43:52.000 Brian                          
2020-04-23 06:50:46.000 Brian                          
2020-04-23 06:55:44.000 Brian                            
2020-04-23 07:35:23.000 Brian                        
2020-04-23 07:41:32.000 Brian                         
2020-04-23 07:47:43.000 Brian                           
2020-04-23 07:54:51.000 Ange                              
2020-04-23 07:58:11.000 Ange                                
2020-04-23 08:02:08.000 Brian                           
2020-04-23 08:06:25.000 Ange                               
2020-04-23 08:11:38.000 Brian                           
2020-04-23 08:39:31.000 Brian                          
2020-04-23 08:42:04.000 Brian                            
2020-04-23 08:59:25.000 Simon                          
2020-04-23 09:07:31.000 Ange                               
2020-04-23 09:27:37.000 Simon                            
2020-04-23 09:28:48.000 Brian                           
2020-04-23 09:31:34.000 Brian
```

Any help would be great!

Thank you

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using. Date functions are quite vendor specific.

Answer (score 1):

You would typically use conditional aggregation:

```
select
    rac_fullname
    sum(case when extract(hour from generated_date) = 6 then 1 else 0 end) hour_06,
    sum(case when extract(hour from generated_date) = 7 then 1 else 0 end) hour_07,
    ...
from mytable
where generated_date > current_date
group by rac_fullname
```

You did not tell which database you are using, so the above query uses standard functions `extract()` and `current_date`. The syntax does vary across databases.

Comment: Thank you. We are using SQL 2008 (soon to be upgraded!)